# Simple example of the use of sheaves

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

What would be (one of) the simplest example of a mathematical result which is
solved using the concept of sheaves?

Comment: There is a proof of low dimensional Hodge conjecture by Lefschetz which can be (apparently) easily proved using sheaf cohomology. [Here's the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_conjecture). I wouldn't say this is the simplest...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_problems

Comment: Note that the concept of sheaves is actually quite old and existed long before their formalization. Basically a sheaf is just a way of putting some structure on the set of all "locally-defined functions on a space".

For example, the set of all holomorphic functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ form a (nontrivial) sheaf.

Answer (score 3):

The exponential sheaf sequence
$$
0\to \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\cdot 2\pi i} \mathcal O_X\xrightarrow{exp} \mathcal O_X^*\to 0
$$

holds on any complex manifold. For the case $X = \mathbb C^*$, we look at a piece of the associated exact cohomology sequence 
$$
\cdots\to H^0(\mathbb C^*, \mathcal O_{\mathbb C^*})\xrightarrow{exp} H^0(\mathbb C^*, \mathcal O_{\mathbb C^*}^*)\to H^1(\mathbb C^*, \mathbb Z)\to \cdots
$$

The fact that $H^1(\mathbb C^*,\mathbb Z)\cong \mathbb Z$ recovers the fact that, in general, one cannot globally construct a complex logarithm of a function on $\mathbb C^*$. In fact, more generally the sequence shows that we can take a global log on any simply-connected complex manifold (or even more generally, I suppose this would work on any complex manifold with perfect fundamental group).